# How to run Event Viewer as another user?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, event-viewer

I want to create a shortcut to run Windows Event Viewer as another user, but the following doesn't seem to work.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /noprofile /user:domain\username "C:\Windows\system32\eventvwr.msc /s"
Enter the password for domain\username:
Attempting to start C:\Windows\system32\eventvwr.msc /s as user "dnr\adm_rche490" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - C:\Windows\system32\eventvwr.msc /s
193: C:\Windows\system32\eventvwr.msc /s is not a valid Win32 application.
```

But if I create the shortcut without the `runas` part, it works but with the current logon user.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
C:\Windows\System32>C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /noprofile /user:domain\username "C:\Windows\system32\mmc.exe eventvwr.msc /s"
```